# Union versus Case or other alternative

Tags: sql, oracle, case, union

I have 2 tables which when joined tell me the organization associated with a particular product.  Each organization has a status, 'Active' or 'Legacy.'  I am trying to return only the 'Active' organization unless there is no 'Active' organization, then I want the 'Legacy' organization.  I cannot figure out how to solve for this without a union and I'd prefer not to use a union as some of my queries are very long and involved.

My current method is two subqueries: one for active and one for legacy and then manually combining them in Excel. This is inefficient and annoying. I was hoping perhaps a CASE statement could eliminate the UNION, but so far I have had no luck.  Here is a simplified picture of the issue:

**Organizations Table**

```
|ORG_NAME      |ORG_STATUS|PRODUCT_ID|
|--------------|----------|----------|
|Organization 1|Active    |1         |
|Organization 2|Legacy    |1         |
|Organization 3|Legacy    |2         |
|Organization 4|Active    |3         |
```

**Products Table**

```
|ID|PRODUCT_NAME|
|--|------------|
|1 |Product 1   |
|2 |Product 2   |
|3 |Product 3   |
```

**Desired output:** (Which I do get with a UNION, but I was hoping for a less cumbersome solution.)

```
|PRODUCT_NAME|ORG_NAME      |ORG_STATUS|
|------------|--------------|----------|
|Product 1   |Organization 1|Active    |
|Product 2   |Organization 3|Legacy    |
|Product 3   |Organization 4|Active    |
```

If I use anything but a UNION, I get the below as my output, but I don't want the Legacy org when there is also an Active org.

```
|PRODUCT_NAME|ORG_NAME      |ORG_STATUS|
|------------|--------------|----------|
|Product 1   |Organization 1|Active    |
|Product 1   |Organization 2|Legacy    |
|Product 2   |Organization 3|Legacy    |
|Product 3   |Organization 4|Active    |
```

I feel like there should be a simple way to select which org is populated based on specified criteria, but I cannot figure out the correct criteria to make it work.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Here is the simplified union query:

```
    SELECT PROD.PRODUCT_NAME, ORG.ORG_NAME
      FROM products prod, organizations org
     WHERE PROD.ID = ORG.PRODUCT_ID AND ORG.STATUS = 'Active'
    UNION
    SELECT PROD.PRODUCT_NAME, ORG.ORG_NAME
      FROM products prod, organizations org
     WHERE PROD.ID = ORG.PRODUCT_ID AND ORG.STATUS = 'Legacy'
           AND ORG.PRODUCT_ID NOT IN (SELECT PROD.ID
                                        FROM products prod, organizations org
                                       WHERE ORG.STATUS = 'Active')
```

I have tried CASE in both the select and where statements, but can't get it to work. Below is one of the attempts, but this doesn't take into account the join between the organization and the product and just gives me all the combinations.  I tried concatenating the org and product to give me a single variable to work with, but that didn't help either.  Maybe it can't be done?

```
WHEN ORG.STATUS = 'Active' THEN ORG.ORG_NAME
ELSE ORG.ORG_NAME
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic function `row_number` to determine the "best" row and then select just that.

```
select *
  from (
select o.org_name, o.org_status, p.product_id, p.product_name,
       row_number() over (partition by p.product_id 
                              order by case when o.org_status = 'Active'
                                            then 1
                                            else 2
                                        end asc) rn
  from products p
       join organizations o 
         on p.product_id = o.product_id
) 
 where rn = 1;
```

Here's an [example from liveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/lj2d71tei81scdd3908l9pvoe)

Comment: I'm following you right up to the point where I select for just row number 1.  I used your example from liveSQL (Statement 34) and I can get exactly the same output, but the goal is to eliminate RN 2.  From your query above I see how you did it in the from statement, but I don't know how you do it when you right it like the statement in liveSQL (which is really nice.)

Comment: @ShandaFin - In the answer I posted, I wrapped the whole thing in an inline view with the predicate `where rn = 1`.  It looks like I saved my LiveSQL session before I ran that version of the query, I just put it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT PROD.PRODUCT_NAME, ORG.ORG_NAME, MIN(ORG.STATUS) as OrgStatus
FROM   products prod, organizations org
WHERE  PROD.ID = ORG.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY PROD.PRODUCT_NAME, ORG.ORG_NAME
```

This of course relies on the fact that Active sorts before Legacy...
This also assumes that there is `1:1` relationship between products and organizations.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Therein lies the problem.  I have a 1:2 relationship between some of the products to orgs.  Loved this idea for its simplicity, though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use-case for a lateral join:

```
select p.*, o.org_name, o.order_status
from products p left join lateral
     (select o.*
      from organizations o
      where o.product_name = p.product_name
      order by o.order_status   -- "Active" before "Legacy"
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) o
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: I'm able to get this to run, but I'm still getting 4 rows, not 3. There is actually a third table involved in my query - one that connects the products and organizations. I simplified the tables in my question, but maybe that's the issue? Here is what I have now: 
`select p.product_name, o.org_name, o.status 
from products p, product_pairs pp  
left join lateral 
(select o.* 
from organizations o 
where pp.ogn_id_established_to = o.ID 
order by o.STATUS 
fetch first 1 row only)  o 
on 1=1 
WHERE  p.ID = pp.prod_id`